# How to separate the CellClick on a DataGridViewButtonColumn of the CellClick event of the whole DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm writing a program in C# and windows forms and I have a problem.

I have a `DataGridView` where I display data in different columns and I added a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. The thing is that I need to separate the `CellClick` event on the `DataGridViewButtonColumn` of the whole `DataGridView.CellClick` event. To resume I would like to invoke a different function if I click on the button in the datagrid than if I click on the other cells.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle click event in Button Column in Datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577297/how-to-handle-click-event-in-button-column-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx), handle the `CellClick` event

```
    dataGridView1.CellClick +=
        new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick);
```

and from within there, check the column number is what you expect.

```
void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore clicks that are not on button cells.  
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex !=
        dataGridView1.Columns["Status Request"].Index) return;
    ....
}
```

Obviously substitute your own column name for "Status Request", or just use the index value.  There's no way (to my knowledge) to attach an event to the button directly, as the button it embeds isn't an actual "Button" object but rather just a GUI trick to make it look like one, so the only thing you can do is check for the column index.