# Adding button in datagridView not working onClick event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this datagridView that takes data from an object.
I add columns like this:

```
dataGridView1.CellClick += dataGridView1_CellClick;
DataGridViewButtonColumn colUsers = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
colUsers.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
colUsers.Text = "Users";
colUsers.Name = "";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colUsers);
```

And I add an onclick event, but it's not working, am I missing something?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.RowIndex > -1 && dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Users")
    {
        name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        gtUserDetails.ShowDialog();
    } 
}
```

I get an error: **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.**

Comment: Check your `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` in `CellClick` event

Comment: What should i check?
If i don't add the new column the click event works, but not with the new one @vallabha

Comment: when you click the button that you have added either exception is getting raised or the event itself is not firing.

Comment: @vallabha, yes, i get this: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: then put a break point at your `if` condition and check `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` in `CellClick` event

Comment: rowindex is 0 and cellindex is 4

Comment: it should be ok according to this

Comment: CellIndex or columnIndex

Comment: Ah, it passes the condition, the code inside doesn't execute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577297/how-to-handle-click-event-in-button-column-in-datagridview

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo thank you, i'm new to this and i still can't modify it properly, please any suggestion based on my code?

Comment: @Perf why you add `DatagridviewButtonColumn` dynamically? why you don't add this column in design window??

Comment: well, this is how i need to do it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `is` operator for checking that: *"is your cell a button of other"*

and use `CellContentClick` instead `CellClick`, because if user click on padding of your button, your event don't raise and wait for clicking ON your button.

Therefor, you can use this event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex,e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewButtonCell)
        (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewButtonCell).Value = "You Clicked Me...";
}
```

Comment: thank you, one question though, how do i get the value of the first column from the row selected?

Comment: this is another question, But I answer you hear. You can use `dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "Changed Me";`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a flaw BUT:

```
colUsers.Name = "";
```

sets your columnname on an empty string instead of "Users". the property Text isn't the same as property Name.

```
colUsers.Name = "Users";
```

EDIT: Constant strings

Whenever you want to use string values inside your code, plz start using a Constant reference. This will keep your string values in 1 place instead of reusing them all the time where the possibility lays that you give in the wrong info, resulting in wrong results.

for example

```
const readonly string UserbuttonName = "Users";

private void CreatebuttonName()
{
  colUsers.Name = UserbuttonName;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.RowIndex > -1 && dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == UserbuttonName)
  DoSomething();
}
```

EDIT: a complete list of properties

Datagridviewbutton column properties :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn_properties(v=vs.110).aspx