# Manually fire button click event in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, click, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I've got a `DataGridView` including a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. The user should be able to use the button directly so I set `EditMode` to `EditOnEnter`. But, the first click didn't fire the `Click` event - It seems like the first click selects/focus the row/column?

So I tried to use the `CellClick` Event:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellClick

 Dim validClick = (e.RowIndex <> -1 And e.ColumnIndex <> -1)
 If (TypeOf dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewButtonColumn And validClick) Then
     dgv.BeginEdit(True)
     CType(dgv.EditingControl, Button).PerformClick()
 End If

End Sub
```

But this solution didn't work either. `EditingControl` always throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577297/how-to-handle-click-event-in-button-column-in-datagridview). It's a c# question however the answer converts to VB.NET so you should be able to pick out bits from.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen this question. The problem is not to run any function/method/event - the problem is, that the **first click always focus the row and didn't fire the CellClick/CellContentClick event even if DataGridView EditMode is EditOnEnter**. Is there any workaround? Whenever the user clicks on a DataGridViewButtonColumn the code behind the DataGridViewButtonColumn should fire...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is a specific event available to handle when a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` cell is clicked. The `DataGridView`’s `Cell_Clicked` and `CellContentClicked` events get fired.

I was not able to get the delay of clicking into the `DataGridView` once then having to click again to fire the button. When I clicked on the `DataGridView` button cell, the `Cell_Clicked` event was immediately fired. Changing the `DataGridView`’s `EditMode` made no difference. The code below simply identifies WHICH cell was clicked from the `Cell_Clicked` event. If the cell clicked was a button column (1 or 2), then I call a created method `ButtonHandler` to handle which button was pressed and to continue on to the correct button method. Hope this helps.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 || e.ColumnIndex == 2) {
    // one of the button columns was clicked 
    ButtonHandler(sender, e);
  }
}

private void ButtonHandler(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) {
    MessageBox.Show("Column 1 button clicked at row: " + e.RowIndex + " Col: " + e.ColumnIndex + " clicked");
    // call method to handle column 1 button clicked
    // MethodToHandleCol1ButtonClicked(e.RowIndex);
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("Column 2 button clicked at row: " + e.RowIndex + " Col: " + e.ColumnIndex + " clicked");
    // call method to handle column 2 button clicked
    // MethodToHandleCol2ButtonClicked(e.RowIndex);
  }
}
```