# Update/Delete buttons inside DataGridView not working after filtering results

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

C# winform application: i added buttons in datagridview in every row for (update,delete). it works fine but when i search data in this gridview the buttons doesn't work on search results.
Here is my code.

```
namespace MyBusiness
{
    public partial class ExpenceDetails : Form
    {
        public ExpenceDetails()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ExpenceDetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            update();
        }

        DataTable data;
        public void update()
        {
            string connectionstring = null;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            connectionstring = @"Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=mrtraders;Trusted_Connection=True";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

            try
            {
                cnn.Open();

                dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 0;

                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Expense", cnn);

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    data = new DataTable();
                    data.Load(reader);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
                }

                DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

                btn.Text = "Update";
                btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);

                DataGridViewButtonColumn btn2 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

                btn2.Text = "Delete";
                btn2.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn2);

                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                myMessageBox my = new myMessageBox("Internal Error...");
                my.ShowDialog();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
            {
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                    //// get ExpenseId//// IMP
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value);
                    string desc = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value);
                    int am = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[3].Value);
                    UpdateExpense a = new UpdateExpense(id,desc,am);
                    a.ShowDialog();

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                    update();

                }
            }
            else if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
            {
                if(e.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value);
                    string connectionstring = null;
                    SqlConnection cnn;
                    connectionstring = @"Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=mrtraders;Trusted_Connection=True";
                    cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

                    try
                    {
                        cnn.Open();

                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Delete FROM Expense where expenseId = '"+id+"' ", cnn);

                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        myMessageBox my = new myMessageBox("Deleted Successfully...");
                        my.ShowDialog();

                        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                        cnn.Close();
                        update();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        myMessageBox my = new myMessageBox("Internal Error...");
                        my.ShowDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView dv = new DataView(data);

            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Description like '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.Table;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably because when you remove/update columns the references to the buttons are garbage collected since they are in local scope and the columns are gone too!

Just try to ensure that the button references stay "alive"!

Comment: Please explain better this phrase: _the buttons don't work on search results_

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577297/how-to-handle-click-event-in-button-column-in-datagridview

Comment: Update/delete button perform its operation before filtering into datagridview! But after that it doesn't work