# How to add button in data grid view in windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I add button in data grid view and call form in button event?
I've tried with toolbox available in Visual Studio 2010.

Once after adding button in tab event another column values to be change...

For example

```
gross_weight= Gross_weight + pallet_weight;
```

here pallet weight column is editable column after tab gross values to be added with pallet weight.

Comment: change the column type to `DataGridViewButtonColumn` in the designer and handle the `CellContentClick` event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577297/how-to-handle-click-event-in-button-column-in-datagridview

Comment: Slai once after tabing pallet column in data grid pallet values to be add to gross weight column how can i do this?? is their any default option??