# Pass parameter from dynamically created HTML-element to onclick event asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Problem summary:
I'm making a request to a database where I fetch created reports based on a user.

These will be listed in a table with a download button with each report where the user can download the report where that button is.

I need to know what report will be used when the button is clicked. This is where the problem is.

My solution so far won't render the `asp:button` - element from the `StringBuilder`. But if I place it in the HTML-file with just a basic input it will show.

My Code behind look like this:

```
SqlDataReader sqlReader = DataFromADatabaseRequest
StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();
table.Append("<table border='1'>");
table.Append(
    "<tr>" +
    "<th>ID</th>" +
    "<th>Name</th>" +
    "<th>Prefix</th>" +
    "</tr>");
if (sqlReader.HasRows)
{
    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        string uniqueIdentifierToFindWhatButtonIsClicked = sqlReader["Prefix"].ToString();

        table.Append("<tr>");
        table.Append("<td>" + sqlReader["Id"] + " </td>");
        table.Append("<td>" + sqlReader["Name"] + " </td>");
        table.Append("<td> <asp:Button id="btn_" + uniqueIdentifierToFindWhatButtonIsClicked + "' class='btnDownloadFile' CommandName=" + uniqueIdentifierToFindWhatButtonIsClicked + "/> </td>");
        table.Append("</tr>");
    }
}
table.Append("</table>");
```

I then send this `tablestring` into an `asp:placeholder` where this table is shown.
Everything works fine. But the button won't show.

If I use like a normal `<input type="button" />` this works but then I can't hook a code-behind event allowing me to pass a parameter.

Thankful for all help.

Comment: You cannot create a aspnet control as a string. Create real Controls.

Comment: You should not generate the html in server side code but instead use GridView- or Repeater -control and use databinding to render the control with the buttons etc.

Answer (score 0):

.NET already has controls for dynamically generating rows with buttons on them.  Take a look at the ASP Repeater items.  You can also use a data grid view control with a templated column.  There are numerous examples.  Don't try and re-invent the wheel my friend.  :)

Here is the grid view sample:
[How to handle click event in Button Column in Datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577297/how-to-handle-click-event-in-button-column-in-datagridview)

Note that, if you want to you can write custom code in the on item data bound if you need to handle things on a row by row basis... such as changing button text or styles or enabling controls based on a particular row's data.

Here's the row data bound technique:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/rowdatabound-event-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/

The trick to mastering dynamic tabular data and functionality with web forms is to totally understand the controls that the .NET framework gives you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks alot. I will look into this.